# React Hook useEffect missing dependencies, running conditionals on button click that triggers state change

Tags: reactjs

[image]

^^^ returnedMovie / returnedBooks are based on a button getting clicked that changes the state of "setBookButtonValue" --> which in turn causes the use effect to run because I've set bookButtonValue as the dependency array. Everything works as expected within the app, aside from the fact that I get this error that doesn't allow it to build out in the end. I've dug around some other forums about this but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around whats going on.

**When I add the dependency arrays React wants me to add, its okay but eventually it will crash the app at a certain point due to them triggering the useEffect when their state changes - which I don't want, I only want "bookButtonValue" to trigger the useEffect.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
    const [searchMultipleBooks, setSearchMultipleBooks] = useState([]);
  const [bookButtonValue, setBookButtonValue] = useState('');
  const [returnedBooks, setReturnedBooks] = useState([]);
  const [returnedMovie, setReturnedMovie] = useState();

  const handleBookChoice = (clickedButton) => {
    setBookButtonValue(clickedButton); 
    setUserInput('')
  }
  // this useEffect will then act once "bookButtonValue" is defined
  useEffect(()=> {

    if (bookButtonValue) {
      const matchedBook = returnedBooks.filter((item) => {
        return item.volumeInfo.title === bookButtonValue;
      })
      if (matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.averageRating === undefined) {
            matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.averageRating = 'not rated'
            matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.outcome = 'winner';
            returnedMovie.outcome = 'loser';
          }
          else if ((returnedMovie.vote_average / 2) > matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.averageRating) {
            matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.outcome = 'loser';
            returnedMovie.outcome = 'winner';
          } else if ((returnedMovie.vote_average / 2) < matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.averageRating) {
            matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.outcome = 'winner';
            returnedMovie.outcome = 'loser';
          } else if ((returnedMovie.vote_average / 2) === matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.averageRating){
            matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.outcome = 'tie';
            returnedMovie.outcome = 'tie';
          }
      setResults([
        {
          type: "movie",
          name: returnedMovie.title,
          description: returnedMovie.overview,
          rating: `${returnedMovie.vote_average / 2}/5`,
          img: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200${returnedMovie.poster_path}`,
          altDescription: `${returnedMovie.title} poster`,
          id: returnedMovie.id,
          outcome: returnedMovie.outcome,
        },
  
        {
          type: "book",
          name: matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.title,
          author: matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.authors[0],
          description: matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.description,
          rating: `${matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.averageRating}/5`,
          img: matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
          altDescription: `${matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.title} cover`,
          id: matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
          outcome: matchedBook[0].volumeInfo.outcome,
        },
      ]);
      
    } else {
    }
  }, [bookButtonValue])
```

Comment: which state `setResults` changes? you are mutating state everywhere which is not good practice

Comment: if your eslint is taking the missing dependencies as an error, change it to a warning to let you build the app

Comment: @buzatto yeah I didn't think that was good. setResults is changing the state that will eventually put data on the page via props to another component